# Compile browserify when files are changed

Tags: coffeescript, webstorm, browserify

I'm using coffeeify plugin to browserify (compiles directly from .coffee files, correctly creates source maps) to compile my modular coffee project. However, manually compiling after each change seems annoying to me.

The best solution so far was to use watchify. However, I'm sure, that there must be a way to set WebStorm file watchers to trigger the compilation automatically. My question is, how to set it correctly (to only trigger when needed,...)?

Comment: are you using `gulp` or `grunt`? there might be the right plugins written for you already.

Comment: Neither, just the WebStorm File Watcher, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can try configuring Browserify as a file watcher in WebStorm, so that it is run every time the file(s) are changed - see https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/new-watcher-dialog.html.

Like:

```
Program: path/to/browserify.cmd
Arguments: -t coffeeify foo.coffee > bundle.js
Working directory: folder where foo.coffee is located
Output paths to refresh: path/to/bundle.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the settings that worked well for me on Windows 10 using Webstorm 2016.2

- File Type: `Coffeescript`
- Scope:  Custom. I just selected my /public and clicked include recursively
- Program: `C:\Users\MYUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm\Browserify.cmd`
- Arguments: `-t coffeeify --debug $FileName$ -o $FileNameWithoutExtension$.js`
- Working directory: `$FileDir$`
- Output paths to refresh: `$FileNameWithoutExtension$.js`